# WhyWorkflow item got suspended?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have created the workflow and subsciribed to finishactivity event, in the finishactivity event i am just writing logs.

when the item enters into the workflow, the item got suspended after finishing the first activity. what could be the reason?

Comment: It usually means there was an error, for example in an automatic activity or in an event. Can you check the Tridion / Tridion Content Manager windows event logs?

Comment: Hey Quirijn, don't be shy! If you put your answers as comments, we'll vote for Chris instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Quirijn, this is the normal state that a workflow item enters if the code in an automated activity throws an error. In order to diagnose this, please post any automated activity code in your question. It is often also worth inspecting your Windows event logs for hints on what has gone wrong.